# What is the best way to generate HTML markup for each playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, soundcloud

I was wondering how I can achieve the following. I make use of the Soundcloud API to import all playlists to a website. This, I have done with the Soundcloud HTTP part.

Now I want to put each playlist/album including the tracklist and cover image of that album inside a `div` element. The holder of that album. The layout of the markup is simple: left a figure that holds the album cover, right an unordered list with the tracks of the album.

What I want to ask is, what the best way is to put every album in a div with every time the same markup.

What I have now is. In my `HTML` a div-holder that holds all the playlist/albums. Then it should fill with the each function.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row albums"></div> <!-- All albums here -->
```

**JS**

```
var albumHolder = $('.albums');
$(playlists).each(function(index, playlist) {
    var playlistID = playlist.id;

    albumHolder.append('<div id="#' + playlistID + '"></div>');

});
```

Above code will create for each playlist a div with the `id` of that playlist inside the albumHolder that holds all the albums.

So in summary: I would like to use the same layout every time and generate that for each album inside that `album div` that I create with above code.

Comment: You might want to look into JavaScript templating engines.

Comment: (Btw., why an _unordered_ list for the album tracks? Tracks on an album are _ordered_ data by their very nature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best way* totally **depends on the nature of your application**!

Say, you have only album and related songs only in the entire page that you can go ahead and re-write the HTML every time!

But if you have other components on the page (for example, menus, search field etc..) in this case it is not a good idea to scrape the entire page! Here you should re-write only parent-div of album and playlist. This way you don't have to reload other stuff and you can provide a better user experience.

Hope this answers your question.

**UPDATE:**

To replace some part of the HTML you can refer the below code

```js
$('#append').click(function(){
 $('#container').append('<b> Hello </b>');
 
});
$('#replace').click(function(){
 $('#container').html('<b> I am just replaced!</b>');
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I would like to say: <span id="container">I am the Dummy Text</span></p>
<button id="replace">Replace Dummy Text</button>
<button id="append">Append Hello</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.  So your advice is to fill only dynamically the content and paste it in the markup that I have already created in HTML?